# Page footer not appearing on Reporting Services 2005 exported-to-PDF report

Tags: reporting-services, pagination

I am trying to migrate a report from Excel to Reporting Services.  The content is in place - each former spreadsheet is now a subreport in a report.

The trouble is, my formatting is misbehaving.  The footer I've set will appear everywhere except in the production export:

- It appears when I'm in BIDS' Preview mode
- If I click "Print" from the BIDS Preview, it appears
- It will appear in the Report Manager preview mode
- It's there if I click "Print" from the Report Manager preview
- If I export to Excel, Web archive, or TIFF from the Report Manager, it appears

However, it *doesn't* appear when I use the Report Manager's "Export" function to export to PDF.  Which is the format I actually want it in.  Sigh.

The footer is part of the outer report, with the subreports (hopefully) smaller than the content so they appear neatly on the one page each.

I'm guessing it's a border issue or something; here are the sizes:

- Main report:
  - Report:
    - PageSize: 29cm, 21cm
    - InteractiveSize: 29cm,21cm
    - Margins: 1cm, 1cm, 1cm, 1cm
  - Body:
    - Size: 27cm,15cm
  - Footer:
    - Size: 27cm, 0.75265cm
- Subreports:
  - Report:
    - PageSize: 27cm, 15cm
    - InteractiveSize: 27cm, 15cm
    - Margins: 0.25cm, 0.25cm, 0.25cm, 0.25cm
  - Body:
    - Size: 27cm, 9cm

I'm tearing my hair out.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textboxes in the footer were set to size 10 font.  The footer was too short to handle this, so it just dropped them.  Increase the footer's height to 1cm, and suddenly they appear...